# Volvo V70 turn light activator

Tags: volvo, part-identification, parts, v70

The left stick behind the steering wheel is missing a piece as you can see here: [image: this picture] [image: and in this one.]

I was wondering if this is replaceable and if so what the part number would be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What year and engine is your V70?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 its from 2001. Im not sure how to answer the engine question tho, 5 cylinder with 170pk?

Comment: Here's a [link for you.](http://www.volvopartswebstore.com/cars/Volvo/2001/V70/car-parts.html)

Comment: Such small parts are rarely sold separately. I believe your V70 is a second generation one, so your best bet is hitting the breakers yard and picking up a used stick for cheap.

Comment: For small parts like this where the dealer only sells a larger, expensive assembly a junk yard can be a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the parts list for [Volvo online here.](http://www.volvopartswebstore.com/)  The link of interest will be [Home> Volvo> V70> 2001> Electrical system> Switches, turn indicators, main and dipped beams, WIPER/WASHER](http://www.volvopartswebstore.com/showAssembly.aspx?ukey_assembly=242169&ukey_make=865&ukey_model=12011&modelYear=2001&ukey_category=7858)

And it looks like the smallest part they sell is the entire turn signal switch. It looks like they run between $67 and $148.. Hmm.. not cheap.  The price depends on the options, and as I suspect your luck is just like mine, yours is closer to the $148 number.

Another alternative is to check the parts window at your local Volvo dealership, but I suspect they will have similar results and prices as shown above.

Do you still have the broken parts from the original one? This might be a fun and rewarding 3D plastic printed part exercise.  You'd have to "design it" with a CAD system (I use SolidWorks) but there are other options available.  You need a complete 3D digital model of the part.  Then you could just print out a new one.  I would recommend black ABS for the material. I'm pretty sure the broken part is ABS, so that's a match.

Oh, wow.  I just checked.  You can [buy grey ABS as well](http://gizmodorks.com/abs-3d-printer-filament).  A roll is around $25 depending where you look.

Comment: Remember, the OP was *only* asking for the part number. We don't want this to look like a "shopping question", which I assumed it wasn't.

Comment: Funny, I look at purchasing parts squarely in the domain of vehicle repair, but "shopping questions" fall into the realm of "What kind of car should I buy, what kind of options do I need?"  I'm definitely not assuming this is a shopping question.  And my guess is this person has already been to the dealer and is disappointed to find out that the part they really want isn't available.  We've all been there. Mumble, mumble.  This really would be a perfect 3D printing exercise.